# WebSocket connection to 'wss://url/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I keep getting this error :WebSocket connection to 'wss://url/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:  for one week in production not locally.
Here is my websocket connection nodeJs in server.js file:

```
`server.js :
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const server = http.createServer(app);  
const io = socketIO(server);
//const io = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;
app.set('io', io);`
```

Here is my websocket connection in Angular:

```
`environment.prod.ts :
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  basUrl :  "https://okbaclinical-backend.herokuapp.com/api/",
  socketBaseUrl : "wss://okbaclinical-backend.herokuapp.com"
};
`

`
notifications.ts :
//imports : 
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.prod';
//declarations : 
  private websocket = environment.socketBaseUrl;
  socket;
//code : 
    this.socket = io(this.websocket, {transports: ['websocket']});
    this.socket.on('notification', (res) => {
      this.getNotification();
      });
`
```

I tried to upgrade and downgrade by using the following versions: 1.7.0, 2.4.0, 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

wss means you are using ssl so you should require https and provide certicficates

Answer (score -1):

Proxy passing your web socket requests might help.

Comment: I'm new in web development, can tell me plz how to create a proxy and use it in this case?(ps: im using angular and nodejsfront and back consecutively)